# New button creation inside JScrollPane

Tags: java, jdbc, jbutton, jscrollpane, windowbuilder

I've written a so called 'error less' code but I'm facing certain problems whilst using the application. This used to work perfectly before but as soon as I took the code over to the windowbuilder as a Jframe it started to not work.
Here's my code:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.RootPaneContainer;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Color;


public class AdminClass implements ActionListener  {

ProjectButton[] buttons = new ProjectButton[35];

//Creating data field for unique Ids in the form of array list
ArrayList<Integer> uniqueIDList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
String[] projectNames;
int[] uniqueIds;

Connection conn1 = null;
Statement stmt1 = null;

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Admin Panel");
private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Add New Project");

public AdminClass() {
    panel.setLayout(null);
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Welcome to Admin Panel");
    label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
    label.setBounds(148, 0, 188, 45);
    panel.add(label);
    btnNewButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    btnNewButton.setFont(new Font("Yu Gothic", Font.BOLD, 13));
    btnNewButton.setBounds(0, 46, 482, 45);

    btnNewButton.addActionListener(this);
    panel.add(btnNewButton);

    JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("Existing Projects");
    label_1.setFont(new Font("Tunga", Font.BOLD, 15));
    label_1.setBounds(183, 90, 102, 45);
    panel.add(label_1);

    conn1 = sqliteConnection.dbConnector();

    try{
          Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
          conn1.setAutoCommit(false);
          stmt1 = conn1.createStatement();
          ResultSet rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM Project;" );

          List<String> projectNameList = new ArrayList<String>();

          while ( rs1.next() ){
              int id = rs1.getInt("uniqueid");
              String projectName = rs1.getString("name");

              projectNameList.add(projectName);
              uniqueIDList.add(id);
          }

          // Converting array list to array
          projectNames = new String[projectNameList.size()];
          projectNameList.toArray(projectNames);

          uniqueIds = convertIntegers(uniqueIDList);


          rs1.close();
          stmt1.close();
          conn1.close();
    }
    catch ( Exception e1 ) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1);    
    }

    // Adding buttons to the project
    try{
        for (int i = 0; i < projectNames.length; i++){
            buttons[i] = new ProjectButton(projectNames[i]);
            buttons[i].setId(uniqueIds[i]);

            panel.add(buttons[i]);
            buttons[i].addActionListener(this);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e2){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e2);
    }

    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(25, 133, 430, 307);
    panel.add(scrollPane);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    for (int j = 0; j < buttons.length; j ++){
        if (e.getSource() == buttons[j]){
            AdminStatus sc = new AdminStatus(buttons[j].getId());
            frame.dispose();
        }
    }

    if (e.getSource() == btnNewButton){

        frame.dispose();
        WindowProjectAdmin wpa = new WindowProjectAdmin();

    }

}

//Method to convert integar array list to integar array
public int[] convertIntegers(List<Integer> integers)
    {
        int[] ret = new int[integers.size()];
        for (int i=0; i < ret.length; i++)
        {
            ret[i] = integers.get(i).intValue();
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

}

I want buttons to spawn inside my scroller. Someone edit the code too if you can to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `null Layout` is generally not recommended. You should reconsider this approach.I would use for example `GridLayout`, this way your buttons should appear without problem.

If you want to use `null Layout`, you should use `setBounds()`, on every component inside container with `null Layout`. So you need to "manually" choose it size and location on `JPanel`.

Whats more, I think this is not good idea, to only display message on `JOptionPane` in case of exception, without `printStackTrace`(). This way it will by much harder to debug it.